# Using $inject in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have following code for the service written by someone else:

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('maintenance.portability.module')
        .factory('selectedSamplesSvc', service);

    service.$inject = ['$resource'];

function service() {
}
})();
```

I just want to be able to do following:

1. Inject '$resource'
2. use an instance of $resource  inside my service

How can I do that?

Comment: This code was written wrong. The parameter should be specified for the service, `service($resource) {`. That's all.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation

Answer (score 1):

> 3 ways you can inject a service:

1. Passing a dependency as Function Arguments

   ```
    app.controller("TestController", function ($scope) {
     $scope.message = "Hey I am passed as function argument" 
    });
   ```
2. Passing a dependency as Array Arguments

   ```
    app.controller("TestController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     $scope.message = "Hey I am passed in as array argument" 
    }]);
   ```

   *Passing dependencies as Array Arguments does not break application when we minify the application.*
3. Passing a dependency using the $inject service

   ```
    function TestController($scope){
      $scope.greet = "I am injected using inject service";
    }

    TestController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    app.controller('TestController', TestController);
   ```

Yours is the 3rd way. For injecting, $resource service you need **ngResource** module when you set up an angular app.

```
angular.module('test',['ngResource'])
```

Comment: answer is incomplete, still need the function arguments

Comment: @charlietfl: I have added snippets for each way.

Comment: @CoffeeBean, did it answer you question.